# Does a transaction work for statements across multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm using JDBC with mysql. I have a pretty complex series of inserts and updates that I'm doing in a single transaction. This seems to work for the most part, but about 1% of the time I find that the data in one of my tables is in an inconsistent state.

I'm rolling back the transaction if an error occurs, but am not sure how to start debugging. My setup generally looks like:

```
try {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);  

    PreparedStatement stmt1 = conn.prepareStatement("insert into table1");
    stmt1.executeUpdate();
    stmt1.close();

    PreparedStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareStatement("update table2");
    stmt2.executeUpdate();
    stmt2.close();

    ... more statements ...

    conn.commit();
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
    conn.rollback();
}
```

I'm using a 2010 version of mysql. I might try updating that, but I have a feeling it's more something in my application code that's causing the inconsistency.

Are there any debugging tools I might find helpful at the database level to help? Any other pointers? I'm using JDBC with all default settings, I wonder if there is any stricter transaction level I need to use for this kind of scenario?

Thanks

----- Note -----
All my tables are InnoDb.

Comment: The first thing you need to check is if you're using MyISAM or InnoDb tables. MyISAM does not support transactions.

Comment: Confirmed all my tables are InnoDb.

Comment: transaction level read committed?

Comment: Where's your .begin() for the transaction? Shouldn't you throw a new exception after calling conn.rollback()? (I think that the database should issue rollback by default on close, if commit was not called) You could test if it's indeed programming error or database bug by throwing an exception in between the statements.

Comment: Yes I may try transaction level read-committed.

Comment: Hmm if I'm using read-dirty, then would it be possible for one thread to grab a clean snapshot, some of the table modifications begin, now thread B executes and grabs a dirty snapshot before the transaction is complete - now thread A finishes, and thread B finishes afterwards, but with the original dirty data?

Comment: @SamiKorhonen JDBC has implicit transaction starts if auto commit is disabled, so you don't call begin (you can't as the API doesn't even provide that option)

Comment: @Sebas - for InnoDb, the default is 'TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ', which should be as consistent as 'read committed'. So should be ok there.

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. Interesting. Yes, it should work. We used really huge transactions accross multiple tables many times, never experienced even strange things...
Are you sure it is not you who produce the inconsistency (whatever this means here, you didn't specify this)? By simply inserting/updating wrong things? :-)

Just an idea - we ran into this several times. Deadlock resolving. DB servers used to handle that. The chance a deadlock occurs is higher if you have several parallel threads and the transaction blocks are manipulating more tables. In this case some of your transactions could be aborted (and rolled back) by the DB server itself. And those transactions will result in an error.

The code you wrote above only rollbacks in the exception case (aborted transaction already rolled back, so it doesn't do too much..), but have you tried to print/log the exceptions? If not you should.

Of course transactions are running separated from each other. But this could explain why you experience this strange behaviour in only 1-2% of the cases...

You should check the logs of your mysql server too. It is also possible the server itself fails for any reason. And one more tip: you may try to run "mysqltop" (or "mtop", hope I remember the name of this tool correctly..). This is able to monitor and show you what happens inside the DB server. However it is mostly used to track the performance of our sqls, this also shows failures. Maybe running this could also help you out...

Comment: Yes it's likely something in my application code, I am putting in further debugging to try and catch what's happening. At least I have some basic sanity checks now as a result of this post (InnoDB should be ok, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you use DDL (create table, alter table, and so on) in your statements?

I am not sure about MySQL but it may not be able to roll back DDL statements.

For example:

- PostgreSQL can rollback DDL,
- Oracle performs commit before executing DDL.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-roll-back.html

Comment: Thanks, I am not creating tables in my transactions - I should be ok here then?

Comment: Yes, it should be ok. Another my idea could be that some other process accesses the same connection and performs a commit concurrently...